# How to check if dataguard is working properly?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, dataguard

I've a requirement for configuring data guard, but I haven't done it in the past. I'm using Oracle 11g database in Windows platform. On reading several blogs and tutorials in Internet, I managed to learn about data guard and configured primary and standby databases in two separate remote servers.I'm still not getting a clear picture of this. However, I've installed and configured primary database which is running in archivelog mode and standby which was installed using Software only method. I guess the configuration is almost complete, but not sure how to ensure it.

Does the changes made in primary get automatically affected in standby? Or, do I need to run any command to make it parallel every time?

Comment: Have you actually created the standby database? Your question isn't clear

Comment: Tim Hall has an excellent write up of how to configure dataguard and check that log shipping and apply are working: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/data-guard-setup-11gr2

Comment: @KrisJohnston Thanks for the blog. But, I didn't understand the purpose of using Data Guard Broker to configure and manage standby database in Oracle 11g R2.

Comment: The purpose of the DG Broker is ease of setup, ease of failover/switchover.  Also, Fast Start Failover must use the broker.

Answer (score 0):

If it is configured, all things are automatic. No need to run any command to sync standby. 
Yes,  easiest way to check whether it's working or not is just cross check record count of a table at both side after inserting some records at primary. You should get those at standby too. 
There are other ways too. But try this first.  Thanks.

Comment: Inserting records at primary, then checking standby isn't practical in a physical standby configuration since the standby is in mount mode (unless you are licensed for Active Data Guard).  You have to stop redo apply, alter database open; check the records, shutdown immediate; startup mount; start redo apply.  Although you can use that as a sanity check the first time you set up a DG environment, there are far easier ways to check that log shipping + apply are working (which Tim Hall says how to do in the blog I linked to in my comment on the question).

Answer (score 0):

Data Guard is a replay of a redo stream from the primary database against a standby database. The easiest way to validate that Data Guard is working would be to connect to the broker and show database . It'll show you the apply lag which an indication of how far behind the standby database is.

You can also look at the v$log view to see which rows have been are categorized.

You can also look at v$datafile on the primary vs. standby to see the checkpoint_time for each datafile.